# Problems with Clone gameObject in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, game-development

Im trying to make collision work for the GameObject Clone, but is not working

The newWaterBottle i wanted to collide with player same as the original WaterBottlePrefab, but is not working, newWaterBottle is spawning perfect but collision not work

[Game Files](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/418f0527df1102dbacb629d7b1c3e2cf20221229154915/bdff94)

Here is the Code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using TMPro;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
public Image healthBar;
public float healthAmount = 100f;
// get WaterBottle game Tag
public GameObject waterBottlePrefab;
// get player game Tag
public GameObject player;

public GameObject scoreText;


int score = 0;

TextMeshProUGUI scoreText_test;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    scoreText_test=scoreText.GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();
    StartCoroutine(SpawnWaterBottles());    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    

    if (healthAmount <= 0){
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
    }

    // if player detect collision with waterBottle display in console "You drink water"
    if (player.GetComponent<Collider2D>().IsTouching(waterBottlePrefab.GetComponent<Collider2D>()))
    {
        score += 1;
        Debug.Log("You drink water");
        Heal();

        // set active false the waterBottle
        waterBottlePrefab.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        // From the begin of the game, the player will be take automatically 1 damage per second
        TakeDamge(5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    scoreText_test.SetText(score.ToString());
}

IEnumerator SpawnWaterBottles()
{
    while (true)
    {
        // Wait for a random interval of time between 10 and 20 seconds
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(5, 15));

        // Spawn a new water bottle at a random distance between 30 and 40 meters in front of the player
        Vector3 spawnPos = player.transform.position + (player.transform.forward * Random.Range(30f, 40f) + new Vector3(40f, 2f, 0));
        GameObject newWaterBottle = Instantiate(waterBottlePrefab, spawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        newWaterBottle.SetActive(true);

    scoreText_test.SetText(score.ToString());

    // Player colision with newWaterBottle
    if (player.GetComponent<Collider2D>().IsTouching(newWaterBottle.GetComponent<Collider2D>()))
    {
        score += 1;
        Debug.Log("You drink waterson");
        Heal();

        // set active false the waterBottle
        newWaterBottle.SetActive(false);
    }
    else
    {
        // From the begin of the game, the player will be take automatically 1 damage per second
        TakeDamge(5f * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
}

// Coroutine to spawn water bottles along the road at ground level
    // Method to heal the player
void Heal()
{
    // Increase the health amount by 10
    healthAmount += 100;

    // Clamp the health amount to 100
    healthAmount = Mathf.Clamp(healthAmount, 0, 100);

    // Update the health bar UI
    healthBar.fillAmount = healthAmount / 100f;
}

// Method to take damage from the player
void TakeDamge(float amount)
{
    // Decrease the health amount by the amount passed in
    healthAmount -= amount;

    // Clamp the health amount to 100
    healthAmount = Mathf.Clamp(healthAmount, 0, 100);

    // Update the health bar UI
    healthBar.fillAmount = healthAmount / 100f;
}
}
```

This is The part where "clone collision hapen"

```
if (player.GetComponent<Collider2D>().IsTouching(newWaterBottle.GetComponent<Collider2D>()))
{
    score += 1;
    Debug.Log("You drink waterson");
    Heal();

    // set active false the waterBottle
    newWaterBottle.SetActive(false);
}
else
{
    // From the begin of the game, the player will be take automatically 1 damage per second
    TakeDamge(5f * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

I tried with Debug.Log() I thoutht it will be the problem with set active or score but no.